# Why can't I call a method with arguments inside get_context_data?

Tags: django

I don't understand why can't I call a method with arguments inside get_context_data. By removing the argument It works. What's the recommended way of changing the class based view context before sending to the template ?

```
class CustomerReportView(TemplateView):
    """Generate Customer Reports based on acct_id"""

    def whoami(self, username):
        """ 
        returns following information about the currently logged-in user 
        {'Name':'', 'Email':''}
        """
        records = {'Name':username, 'Email':'john.doe@email.com'}
        return records

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CustomerReportView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = self.whoami('john.doe@email.com')
        return context
```

Comment: Do you get any error? And why are you calling `whoami` in that way? Couldn't you just use `self.whoami('john.doe@email.com')`?

Comment: The error message is:

TypeError at /reports/customer/123GDFsdfasdf/

whoami() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8080/reports/customer/123GDFsdfasdf/
Django Version:  1.5.5
Exception Type:  TypeError
Exception Value:  

whoami() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: Sorry that's how I am calling it. self.whoami('john.doe@email.com')

Comment: Why did you remove `self` from the definition of `whoami`? It was correct with `self`. Which way do you have it in your code? (If you do not have `self` as the first argument, then that is the source of your error.

Comment: if I add self I get this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7272234/

Comment: That's because you fixed the error with `whoami` and it's on to the next error in your code! Can't help you with that one because it refers to an unposted function and there's no context/line number.

Comment: my bad here! it's all correct. As you said it's elsewhere... Should I delete this question?

Comment: remember that every member method in python needs a first argument in the definition so python can inject the instance of that member, you can call it anyway but it's conventional to call it "self", if you define your method as `def whoami(username): ...` then python will inject the instance in username. If you call that same method as `self.whoami('john@example.com')` then you are implicitly calling it with 2 arguments.